# Gremlin query to get k distance vertices and edges connecting them

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I want to start from a given vertex and get all connected vertices and edges up to a k distance. 
The output should include all edges that connect the included vertices (even if that edge is at k+1 distance) so that we have a complete sub-graph.

Imagine we have this:

```
g.addV('person').property('name', 'a').as('va')
 .addV('person').property('name', 'b').as('vb')
 .addV('person').property('name', 'c').as('vc')
 .addV('person').property('name', 'd').as('vd')
 .addV('person').property('name', 'e').as('ve')
 .addV('person').property('name', 'f').as('vf')
 .addV('person').property('name', 'g').as('vg')
 .select('va').addE('knows').to('vb')
 .select('vb').addE('knows').to('vc')
 .select('vc').addE('knows').to('vd')
 .select('vd').addE('knows').to('ve')
 .select('ve').addE('knows').to('va')
 .select('ve').addE('knows').to('vf')
 .select('vf').addE('knows').to('vg')
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYEBpm.png]

`a->b->c->d->e->(a)` and `e->f->g`

If we start at **c** with a distance of 2 we should have

```
a->b->c->d->e->(a)
```

With this query

```
g.V().has('person','name','c')
     .repeat(bothE().dedup()
                    .store("e")
                    .bothV()
                    .dedup()
                    .store("v"))
     .times(2)
     .cap('e','v')
```

I can get `a->b->c->d->e` but we lose the `e->a` edge

With this query

```
g.V().has('person','name','c')
     .repeat(bothE().dedup()
                    .store("e")
                    .bothV()
                    .dedup()
                    .store("v"))
     .times(2)
     .bothE()
     .dedup()
     .store('e')
     .cap('e','v')
```

we get the extra edges that connect the outer vertices but we also get an edge the connects an outside vertex **f**
We get `a->b->c->d->e->(a)` but also `e->f`

How can we get only the k distance vertices and edges connecting them?

Comment: This seems to work although with some duplicated edges:


    g.V().has('person','name','c').sideEffect(repeat(bothE().dedup().aggregate('e').bothV().dedup().aggregate('v')).times(2).bothE().dedup().where(\_\_.inV().where(within('v'))).where(\_\_.outV().where(within('v'))).aggregate('e')).cap('v','e')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can integrate the break condition in your inner repeat-traversal, that makes it a bit easier:

```
g.V().has('person','name','c').store('v').
  repeat(bothE().where(without('e')).
         choose(loops().is(lt(2)),
                  aggregate('e'),
                  filter(otherV().where(within('v'))).aggregate('e').not(identity())).
         otherV().where(without('v')).aggregate('v')).
  cap('e','v')
```

On your sample graph:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','c').store('v').
......1>   repeat(bothE().where(without('e')).
......2>          choose(loops().is(lt(2)),
......3>                   aggregate('e'),
......4>                   filter(otherV().where(within('v'))).aggregate('e').
......5>                   not(identity())).
......6>          otherV().where(without('v')).aggregate('v')).
......7>   cap('e','v').sideEffect {
......8>      m = it.get()
......9>      println 'Vertices:'
.....10>      m.get('v').each {
.....11>        println "* " + it.value('name')
.....12>      }
.....13>      println 'Edges:'
.....14>      m.get('e').each {
.....15>        println "* " + [it.outVertex(), it.inVertex()]*.value('name').join(' -> ')
.....16>      }
.....17>   }.iterate()
Vertices:
* c
* d
* b
* e
* a
Edges:
* c -> d
* b -> c
* d -> e
* a -> b
* e -> a
```

Comment: Could you please explain what makes the repeat stop? Does it stop when there are no more edges to traverse? That's why the not(identity()) ?

Comment: Exactly. not(identity()) just filters everything.